# Guice injection with inheritance (inject common parameter)

Tags: java, guice, constructor-injection

I currently have a setup where I have a base abstract class defined which takes in one argument that should be same across all implementations, but the others are different. For example:

```
public abstract class A {

    A(String string1, String string2, Clock clock) {
       // initialize vars
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @Inject
    B(Clock clock) {
        super("value1", "value2", clock)
    }
}

public class C extends A {

    @Inject
    C(Clock clock) {
        super("value3", "value4", clock)
    }
}
```

Now, ideally I wouldn't have to inject clock like this in every implementation and could somehow inject it in the base class. I was wondering if there was a way I could use assisted inject but since I am extending the class I don't think that would work.

The other thing I've considered is creating a private subclass inside `Class A` called `Params`, and just inject the `Clock` into that constructor. I'm not a big fan of field injection so was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: I think this is a design issue. I believe instead of inheriting A, you should have 1 concrete class A that you instantiate with the correct parameters (string1, string2) and then inject accordingly (named bindings/ multibindings).

Comment: I think this might be a good usecase for a provider + assisted inject. https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject